# What is the significance of variable = [...variable] in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a variable arg and it has been assigned as follows

```
arg = [...arg];
```

What does this assignment mean ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Comment: While the above documentation may explain the spread operator, I think OP is asking something slightly more specific - *"Why assign a variable **to itself** with a spread operator?"*

Comment: i mean... we could tell you what that does, but is that really what you are asking? because that's pretty obvious given the documentation on the subject or a few console.logs.

Comment: The significance is that whoever wrote this needs to learn how to write clearer code.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to ask if the array has been filtered as follows args.forEach((Item: any) => {...} .                                                        followed by args= [...args]; What is the significance of the args = [...args] ?

Comment: Last comment is as vague as your initial question

Answer (score -3):

*Assuming the original `arg` is an array*

What happens here is best demonstrated using an example

```
const x = [1,2,3,4];
const y = [...x];
x == y; // false
x === y; // false
x[0] == y[0]; // true
x[0] === y[0]; // true
```

So while the content of the array has remained identical, the array itself is another reference. So this created a copy of the array so the original array is not modified.

An example of this can be in a method

```
function example1(x) {
  x = [...x];
  x[0] = 0;
  return x;
}
function example2(x) {
  x[0] = 0;
  return x;
}

const a = [1,2,3];
console.log(a);
const b = example1(a);
// The input variable is not mutated
console.log(a); // [1,2,3]
console.log(b); // [0,2,3]
const c = example2(a);
// The input variable is mutated as well
console.log(a); // [0,2,3]
console.log(c); // [0,2,3]
```

Comment: Based on the question, there is quite some room for guessing. For a code quality perspective it does not seems right to spread an string into an array like this. The most probably use case would be to quickly create a copy of an array to prevent touching the original reference

Comment: Yeah, I had removed my comment upon realizing. That being said, I haven't downvoted - though I have a hunch that it may be because you've submitted a "guess" as an answer (as you yourself have acknowledged).